# Find a non-zero non-maximal proper ideal on the ring of real functions

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Consider the ring of real functions (not necessarily continuous) with the usual sum and product operations.
I was able to prove that every set of the form $$ M_r := \left\{f | f(r)=0\right\} $$
where r is a real constant, is a maximal ideal.
Now I’m asked to find some other ideal that is non-zero, proper and not maximal.
I know it must not contain any maximal ideal and I believe this has something to do with the discontinuous functions, but I couldn’t reach an example.

Comment: You mean functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: How about functions that are zero at two specified points?

Comment: "I know it must not contain any maximal ideal"... by definition of "maximal ideal", the only ideals that contain a maximal ideal are the maximal ideal itself, or the whole ring. You want something that is *properly contained* in a maximal ideal.

Comment: @Lubin yes! Exactly that

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh, I see my confusion now. I was thinking about the example you gave but thought it wouldn’t work. Thank you!